# How to connect to someone else's public Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Apologies if this is a very basic question.

I'm just starting to get to grips with Kafka and have been given a kafka endpoint and topic to push messages to but I'm not actually sure where, when writing the consumer, to specify the end point. Atm I've only had experience in creating a consumer for a broker and producer that is running locally on my machine and so was able to do this by setting the bootstrap server to my local host and port.

I have an inkling that it may be something to do with the advertised listeners settings but I am unsure how it works.

Again sorry if this seems like a very basic question but I couldn't find the answer

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Advertised listeners are a broker setting. If someone else setup Kafka, then all you need to do is change the bootstrap address

If it's "public" over the internet, then chances are you might also need to configure certificates & authentication

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a public cluster is same as connecting to a local deployment.
Im assuming that your are provided with a FQDN of the cluster and the topic name.

You need to add the FQDN to the `bootstrap.servers` property of your consumer and subscribe to the topics using the `subscribe()`

you might want to look into the `client.dns.lookup` property if you want to change the discovery strategy.

Additionally you might have to configure the `keystore` and a `truststore` depending on the security configuration on the cluster